# How to remove double header with react-navigation?

Tags: react-navigation, react-navigation-stack, react-navigation-v5

My React Native 0.61.5 uses `react-navigation 5.1`. Here is the root navigation code:

```
const BTab = createBottomTabNavigator();
const Stack = createStackNavigator();
export default function App() {

  //const Appscreen = () => (<AppScreen data={data}/>);

  return (
    <NavigationContainer>
      <Stack.Navigator InitialRouteName="Splash">
        <Stack.Screen name="Splash" component={SplashScreen}}/>
        <Stack.Screen name="App" component={AppScreen} } />
      </Stack.Navigator>

    </NavigationContainer>
  );
}
```

The component `AppScreen` return a stack like this:

```
return (
    <NavigationContainer independent={true}>
      <BTab.Navigator>
          <BTab.Screen name="Event" component={Eventstack} />
          <BTab.Screen name="Group" component={Groupstack} />
          <BTab.Screen name="Contact" component={Contactstack} />
      </BTab.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
  );
```

I notice that on the screen there are double header:

[image]

How can I remove the `App` header and only keep the `Group`?

Comment: Unrelated to your question, but remove `NavigationContainer indepenent={true}`. You're supposed to use only one `NavigationContainer` at the root of your app. Another problem is that you're defining `AppScreen` inside the `App` component. You need to move it outside.

Comment: Agree, I added 2nd NavigationContainer to see if the extra header disappears. Did you mean having AppScreen as a separate functional component? The SplashScreen is just for retrieving data which require async. The App component looks a little awkward.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

add with the screen that you want to hide the header.

```js
options= {{
  headerShown: false
}}
```

For further reading, kindly have a look at https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/#headershown